# Can blade yield to a section in the same file?

Tags: laravel-4, templating, laravel-blade

I have file master.blade.php, which contains `@yield('mainsection')`. Then I have another file, with:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('mainection')
    test1
    @yield('othersection')
@stop

@section('othersection')
    test2
@stop
```

I can see `test1`, but not `test2` - from which I conclude that blade does not allow you to yield to a section defined in the same file. Is there any way to work around that? Or will I have to add a third file between these two, to contain the mainsection and yield to othersection?

Answer (score 13):

it can be shown, but @section must be written before @yield

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('othersection')
  test2
@stop

@section('mainection')
  test1
  @yield('othersection')
@stop
```